# Is the extension of a torsion free group by a torsion free group necessarily torsion free?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinite-groups, torsion-groups

My instinct tells me the above isn't true, although I am having trouble finding a counterexample.

Hints on where to look for a counterexample would be much appreciated. Hopefully there is some semidirect product which does the trick.

The question arose when I was studying another proof about torsion free groups, and the fact they didn't appeal to this result seems to suggest it isn't true.

Comment: Did you try to prove the claim? You should always try it before looking for counterexamples.

Comment: @Mark: Not sure I agree with "always". But one should certainly keep both *true* and *false* in mind as options to be considered, despite one's instinct.